# How can I send a json response which contains complex objects

Tags: c#, postman

Hello everyone I'm working on API which contains many objects inside its Json Response. I am using the postman for testing.

Every time I trace my code the response is filled correctly inside Visual studio until we reached to the level that the response must be displayed on Postman. It shows me that it couldn't get any response.

My c# code :

```
 public SMS1234EvaluationSearchResponse SMS1234EvaluationSearchButton(int ChannelsValue, bool ClosedSMS, bool Rerouted, bool Evaluated, bool NotEvaluated, bool Nominated, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate, CycleUserInfo oCycleUserInfo, int PageSize, int CurrentPageIndex, int QuerySelectedIndex, List<LookupObject> NamesTo)
    {
        DirectoryService oDirectoryServices = new DirectoryService();
        ErrorModel error = new ErrorModel();
        SMS1234EvaluationSearchResponse oResponse = new SMS1234EvaluationSearchResponse();
        try
        {
            int S1 = 0;
            int S2 = 0;
            int S3 = 0;
            int S4 = 0;
            int S5 = 0;
            int S6 = 0;
            int F1 = 0;
            int F2 = 0;
            int F3 = 0;
            String flg = "";


            if (ClosedSMS)
            {
                S1 = 2; S2 = 2; S3 = 2; S4 = 2; S5 = 2; S6 = 2;
            }
            else if (Rerouted)
            {
                S1 = 5; S2 = 5; S3 = 5; S4 = 5; S5 = 5; S6 = 5;
            }
            else
            {
                S1 = 0; S2 = 1; S3 = 2; S4 = 3; S5 = 4; S6 = 5;
            }

            if (ClosedSMS)
            {
                flg = "0,1,2";
                F1 = 0; F2 = 1; F3 = 2;
            }
            else if (Evaluated)
            {
                flg = "2";
                F1 = 2; F2 = 2; F3 = 2;
            }
            else if (NotEvaluated)
            {
                flg = "0,1";
                F1 = 0; F2 = 0; F3 = 1;
            }
            else if (Nominated)
            {
                flg = "1";
                F1 = 1; F2 = 1; F3 = 1;
            }
            else if (Rerouted)
            {
                flg = "0,1,2";
                F1 = 0; F2 = 1; F3 = 2;
            }

            if (oDirectoryServices.IsSMSAuthorized(1, 2))
            {
                oResponse.NamesFromList = FillUsersList(FromDate, ToDate, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, F1, F2, F3, ChannelsValue, Rerouted, NamesTo);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Evaluated)
                {
                    oResponse.objSMS1234EvaluatedDetailsObject = EvaluateDetails(FromDate, ToDate, Convert.ToString(oCycleUserInfo.UserID), PageSize, CurrentPageIndex, QuerySelectedIndex);
                }
                if (NotEvaluated)
                {
                    oResponse.objSMS1234NotEvaluatedDetailsObject = NotEvaluatedDetails(FromDate, ToDate, Convert.ToString(oCycleUserInfo.UserID), PageSize, CurrentPageIndex, QuerySelectedIndex);
                }
                if (ClosedSMS)
                {
                    oResponse.objSMS1234ClosedSMSObject = ClosedDetails(FromDate, ToDate, Convert.ToString(oCycleUserInfo.UserID), PageSize, CurrentPageIndex, QuerySelectedIndex);
                }
                if (Nominated)
                {
                    oResponse.objSMS1234NominatedObject = NominatedDetails(FromDate, ToDate, Convert.ToString(oCycleUserInfo.UserID), PageSize, CurrentPageIndex, QuerySelectedIndex);
                }
                if (Rerouted)
                {
                    oResponse.objSMS1234RoutedSMSObject = ReroutedDetails(FromDate, ToDate, Convert.ToString(oCycleUserInfo.UserID), PageSize, CurrentPageIndex, QuerySelectedIndex);
                }

            }
            return oResponse;
        }
        catch (UnicamException ex)
        {
            error.ErrorCode = ex.ErrorCode.ToString();
            error.ErrorMessage = ExceptionHandler.GetErrorDescription(ex.ErrorCode.ToString());
            error.ErrorMsgParams = ex.ErrorMsgParameters;
            error.ErrorType = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed;
            oResponse.ErrorObj = error;
            return oResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error.ErrorCode = "Exception";
            error.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
            error.ErrorType = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed;
            oResponse.ErrorObj = error;
            return oResponse;
        }
    }
```

My Response Code :

```
  public class SMS1234EvaluationSearchResponse
{
    private List<LookupObj> _NamesFromList;

    [DataMember]
    public List<LookupObj> NamesFromList
    {
        get { return _NamesFromList; }
        set { _NamesFromList = value; }
    }

    private SMS12345NominatedSMSObject _objSMS1234NominatedObject;

    [DataMember]
    public SMS12345NominatedSMSObject objSMS1234NominatedObject
    {
        get { return _objSMS1234NominatedObject; }
        set { _objSMS1234NominatedObject = value; }
    }

    private SMS1234ClosedSmsObject _objSMS1234ClosedSMSObject;

    [DataMember]
    public SMS1234ClosedSmsObject objSMS1234ClosedSMSObject
    {
        get { return _objSMS1234ClosedSMSObject; }
        set { _objSMS1234ClosedSMSObject = value; }
    }

    private SMS1234ReroutedSMSObject _objSMS1234RoutedSMSObject;

    [DataMember]
    public SMS1234ReroutedSMSObject objSMS1234RoutedSMSObject
    {
        get { return _objSMS1234RoutedSMSObject; }
        set { _objSMS1234RoutedSMSObject = value; }
    }

    private SMS1234NotEvaluatedDetailsObject _objSMS1234NotEvaluatedDetailsObject;

    [DataMember]
    public SMS1234NotEvaluatedDetailsObject objSMS1234NotEvaluatedDetailsObject
    {
        get { return _objSMS1234NotEvaluatedDetailsObject; }
        set { _objSMS1234NotEvaluatedDetailsObject = value; }
    }

    private SMS1234EvaluateDetailsObject _objSMS1234EvaluatedDetailsObject;

    [DataMember]
    public SMS1234EvaluateDetailsObject objSMS1234EvaluatedDetailsObject
    {
        get { return _objSMS1234EvaluatedDetailsObject; }
        set { _objSMS1234EvaluatedDetailsObject = value; }
    }




}
```

API code:

```
 public SMS1234EvaluationSearchResponse SMS1234EvaluationSearchButton(SMS1234EvaluationSearchRequest oRequest)
        {
            SMS1234EvaluationSearchResponse oResponse = new SMS1234EvaluationSearchResponse();
            ErrorModel oError = new ErrorModel();
            try
            {
                ZainCyclesBusiness.ZainCycleTransactions oZainCycleTransactions = new ZainCyclesBusiness.ZainCycleTransactions();
                oResponse = oZainCycleTransactions.SMS1234EvaluationSearchButton(oRequest.ChannelsValue,oRequest.ClosedSMS,oRequest.Rerouted,oRequest.Evaluated,oRequest.NotEvaluated,oRequest.Nominated, oRequest.FromDate,oRequest.ToDate,oRequest.UserInfo,oRequest.PageSize,oRequest.CurrentPageIndex,oRequest.QuerySelectedIndex,oRequest.NamesTo);
                oResponse.ErrorObj = CheckErrorResons(oResponse.ErrorObj);
            }
            catch (UnicamException ex)
            {
                oError.ErrorCode = ex.ErrorCode.ToString();
                oError.ErrorMessage = ExceptionHandler.GetErrorDescription(ex.ErrorCode.ToString());
                oError.ErrorMsgParams = ex.ErrorMsgParameters;
                oResponse.ErrorObj = oError;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                oError.ErrorCode = "Exception";
                oError.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
                oResponse.ErrorObj = oError;
            }

            return oResponse;
        }
```

Comment: So what JSON does it generate and why is that wrong?

Comment: Please post a minimal code allowing us to reproduce ...

Comment: If Postman says that it couldn't get any response, then the problem probably comes just before sending the response and not necessarily from the JSON serialization. Could you share your API controller code or any other relevant piece of code that could help you out ?

Comment: @LaurentS. small code for what ?

Comment: @imad See [mcve].

Comment: @imadsuliman He meant all the relevant code, the code you shared is currently insufficient for us to help you. what you shared is only method calls and doesn't allow us to fully understand what your code is supposed to do :)

Comment: @AntoineThiry sorry I'm beginner in API design and Phrases . I hope my edit  would be helpful